# Page layout using div tag

Tags: css, html

I am trying to design a web page which is divided into 3 regions:-

1) a header region
2) a left navigation pane
3) The main content area

For this, I am presently using the following CSS classes:-

```
    .Content
    {
    position:absolute;
    overflow:auto;
    top:10%;
    left:20%;
    width:80%;
    height:90%;
    }

    .Header
    {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:Blue;
    text-align:center;
    }

    .NavPanel
    {
        position:absolute;
        top:10%;
        left:0;
        height:90%;
        width:20%;
        overflow:auto;
        background-color:Menu;
    }
```

The height and width of body tag are set to 100%.

I dont think this is a very good way of doing what I want to do. For example, when I reduce the height of the browser, the header area reduces proportionally, ultimately vanishing. Also, the page is rendered as expected by Chrome, but for some reason, horizontal scroll bar appears in IE8.

I dont have great knowledge in HTML and CSS, so I just wanted to know if there is any better way of doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to specify an absolute height for the header, e.g.:

```
.Header 
    { 
    position:absolute; 
    left:0; 
    top:0; 
    height:100px; 
    width:100%; 
    background-color:Blue; 
    text-align:center; 
    }
```

You can also specify the header in measures of the font size: `height: 10em` (1 em should be the width of the letter "m"; 1 ex would be the height of the letter "x").

Note that it might be better to remove the "position" attributes both for the header and the content. In this case, positioning would be relative (the default), making the content appear below the header regardless of the size of the header. In that case, remove the "height" attribute for the content.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting a [**`min-height`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/min-height) on the header and using [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries).

For example, you could set `min-height: 2em;` and use a media-query like:

```
@media (max-height: 20em) { /* the min-height for the header = 10% of the max-height used here */
    .content, .navPanel {
        top: 2em; bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3689483)

However, media queries don't work in IE 8 or older.

Comment: And every other browser. I was only talking about IE versions. I'll reword that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you are looking for page layout like this copy and paste this code into any notepad and check it out.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">


        .Container
        {
        background-color:yellow;
        height:100%;
        weight:100%;
        }

        .inner
        {
        float:left;
        top:10%;
        height:90%;
        width:100%
        }

        .Content
        {
        float:left;
        top:10%;
        left:20%;
        width:80%;
        height:100%;
        background-color:skyblue;
        }

        .Header
        {
        float:left;
        height:10%;
        width:100%;
        background-color:Blue;
        text-align:center;
        }

        .NavPanel
        {
            float:left;
            top:10%;
            height:100%;
            width:20%;
            background-color:Menu;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Container">
        <div class="Header"></div>
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="NavPanel"></div>
                <div class="Content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic layout that you can use and expand upon:

http://jsfiddle.net/yUCdb/

Answer (score 0):

You may try;

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div id="viewer"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#header, #sidebar, #viewer {
    position: absolute;
}
#header{
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background: yellow
}
#sidebar {
    top: 10%;
    width: 20%;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: red;
    z-index:100;
}
#viewer {
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: green;
}
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/mczeW/)*** is a live demo.